# How to search for a folder in all the available windows drive using the command prompt?

Tags: windows, cmd

I want to search for a folder in all the drives and I want to get the full pathname of the folder if it exists using the command prompt. How do I do it?

Basically I want to find where the folder "opencv\build\bin" is present and set the environment variable accordingly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you: it will report the last match found.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q u r s t u v w x y z) do (
   if exist "%%a:\" dir %%a:\ /ad /b /s >>"%userprofile%\desktop\folderlist.txt"
 )

find /i "\opencv\build\bin" < "%userprofile%\desktop\folderlist.txt" >"%userprofile%\desktop\folderlistfound.txt"

if exist "%userprofile%\desktop\folderlistfound.txt" (
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%userprofile%\desktop\folderlistfound.txt") do (
    set "foundfolder=%%a"
    echo found at "%%a"
  )
)
if defined foundfolder (
     echo last folder matched at "%foundfolder%"
  ) else (
     echo didn't find the "opencv\build\bin"
  )
```